# Keep only part of string

Tags: php

I have a string that look something like this:

```
/var/www/html/uploads/blabla.mp4
```

How to make it to look like:

```
/uploads/blabla.mp4
```

`blabla.mp4` can change to any string, like: `blablablablablablabla.mp4`

Comment: What of there are more levels of directories? Do you always want the last two parts of the path, or do you always want to remove `/var/www/html`?

Comment: @Chris: Good question.

Comment: Please either clarify what you want (like Chris suggested), and perhaps offer some other examples, and how you would expect them to act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a path, use path tools:

```
$info = pathinfo($string);
echo '/' . basename($info['dirname']) . '/' . $info['basename'];
```